# Checking for empty radio buttons in Perl

Tags: perl, radio-button, error-checking

I new to Perl and had a question. I have a simple page which allows users to respond to survey questions. There are various question and each has 4 choices. My question is that how do I verify that the user has answered all the question. The radio-group names are populate from the database using an incremental id which is what's confusing me. So say question's choices have the radio-group name "1" and another questions radio-group name is maybe "4". I'm not using the CGI.pm module. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By "not using the CGI.pm module," do you mean you're not using any libraries?

Comment: You mention a lot of things, but not what part you are actually having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field with a list of question identifiers.

Comment: Then wait for an evil user to come along and post a different value to the hidden field than the one you intend.  It *might* not blow up...

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a bad idea to trust the client for a list of questions.

Just reuse the code you implemented to **display** the survey. You'll know how you generated the names of the form input fields. Then cycle through all these names and check whether you have a respective HTTP POST field.

For any further questions you need to supply more detailed information on what is your problem.